# using wildcards in ServiceRoute

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF app that used to have multiple services, but now we have refactored them into a single service, however the clients are still going to call them on their older urls.

To acommodate this i use the RouteTable to route them to the single implementation like this

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Services/MyoldService.svc",
                             new MyServiceFactory("MyoldService"), typeof(Service1)));
```

Is it possible to specify that all services go to a single implementation by using some kind of wildcard in the url Pattern of the ServiceRoute ?

So something like

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Services/*.svc",
                             new MyServiceFactory("MyoldService"), typeof(Service1)));
```

or any other way of accomplishing the same goal.

Comment: are you looking for `Filter Tables`?

Comment: see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/772854/WCF-Routing-Service-Part-I-Basic-Concept-Simple-Ro

Comment: is you want to avoid `IgnoreRoute` something OR you want to redirect your new service

Answer (score 0):

try using {dontcare} instead of *
Since ServiceRoute inherits from Route this seems like it should work based on MSDN documentation

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, doesn't seem to like curly brackets.

Comment: From the [reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Activation/System/ServiceModel/Activation/ServiceRoute.cs,ec5812c2847148d7) it seems like it would trhow exception if curly bracket found. Can someone clarify if I understood correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to do this through IIS url re-writing, which does allow wildcards:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module